# When is every submodule pure?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Recall that a module is called

1. semisimple if every submodule is a direct summand
2. pure semisimple if every pure submodule is a direct summand

There is quite a bit of work on semisimple and pure semisimple modules, of course.

My question is

What is a module called if every submodule is pure?

and

What is known about these modules and where can I read about them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmmm, I seem to have found the answer to this question.  In

[Regular and semisimple modules](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-65/issue-2/Regular-and-semisimple-modules/pjm/1102866791.full)

by Cheatham and Smith in 1976, they call a module regular if every submodule is pure.  Regular is of course an overused word, and maybe other people have called this different things.  But the justification makes some sense: if I is a 2-sided ideal of R, then R/I is a regular R-module if and only if R/I is a von Neumann regular ring.

Answer (score 1):

If R is a discrete valuation ring and M is an R-module such that the annihilator of M isn't zero , then every pure submodule of M is a direct summand. You can see some results about the question in the book "Modules over Discrete Valuation Rings" by Krylov and Tuganbaev.